# Find the unpaired number in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array where all the elements are repeated except one:

```
int[] a={2,6,6,2,4,1,4};
```

How can I find the element integer which is unpaired ?

Comment: Tried to take convert into arraylist(asList()) and then iterate through the elements, comparing present with previous. If any are found without pair, throw boolean. This logic aint working correctly.

Comment: Post that code in your question

Comment: Post what you did, community will help if something wrong.

Comment: This is the first time am posting under homework tag. I was asked this question in an interview. Thats why I posted it under homework. I have tried, dint find any solution, so asked here. Upto you all if to answer or close it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accenture interview question - find the only unpaired element in the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644179/accenture-interview-question-find-the-only-unpaired-element-in-the-array)

Comment: @Ajj : You should have come up with your **findings**. This is how SO works. You earlier [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647325/finding-the-length-of-the-string) was like this only. To be honest, did you tried looking for online solution first? May be Mr. Google would have helped you...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a single number in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185/finding-a-single-number-in-a-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accenture interview question - find the only unpaired element in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644179/accenture-interview-question-find-the-only-unpaired-element-in-the-array)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are a few approaches you can take:

- **Approach 1** — O(*n* log *n*): sort the array. Then, iterate over the elements of the sorted array, two at a time (`i=0`, `i=2`, etc.). When `a[i]` and `a[i+1]` are unequal — or when `i+1 == a.length` — you know that `a[i]` is unpaired.
- **Approach 2** — O(*n*<sup>2</sup>): iterate over the elements. For each element `a[i]`, iterate over the elements (in a nested loop) and see if it ever occurs that `a[i] == a[j]` while `i != j`. If not, then `a[i]` is unpaired.
- **Approach 3** — O(*m*), where *m* is the difference between the greatest and the least element (noting that *m* is Ω(*n*)): iterate over the elements, finding the greatest and least values `MIN` and `MAX`. Create an `int[] b = new int[MAX-MIN+1]`. Iterate over the elements again, incrementing `b[a[i]-MIN]` for each element. Then iterate over `b`; when you find `b[j]==1`, `j` is unpaired.

**Note:** You use the term "element integer", but that's not a real term. The above assumes that you mean "integer-valued element". If you actually mean "element *index*", then only Approach 2 can be used without modification. Approach 3 would require a little bit of adjustment, and Approach 1 would require a lot of adjustment. (Of course, once you've found the *value* that occurs only once, you can just iterate over the array one more time to find the *index* of that value — provided you still have the original array order.)

---

**Edited to add:** I don't know how I missed this before — I guess I'm not used to thinking of bitwise operations when writing Java — but the best solution is actually:

- **Approach 4** — O(*n*): compute the bitwise-XOR, `^`, of all the elements of the array. This is the unpaired element. You see, XOR is commutative and associative, so `2^6^6^2^4^1^4` is the same as `1^(2^2)^(4^4)^(6^6)`; and `x^x` is always `0`, so the pairs always cancel either other out. You can just write:

  ```
  int result = 0;
  for(int i : a)
      result ^= i;
  ```

  to compute the unpaired element. (To get the *index* of the unpaired element, you'd then iterate over the array again, looking for `result`.)

Comment: For the first approach you could also need `O(N)` space depending on the sorting algorithm

Comment: Can anyone please share a source where I can learn how to calcultae the complexities ? I mean O(n), O(log n). I dont know what they mean.                  Edit: Got one--> http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/big-o-notation/

Answer (score 2):

You could use a map to keep a count of how many times a number has been seen. There are undoubtedly better ways of doing it, but it'll work.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    int[] a = { 2, 6, 6, 2, 4, 1, 4 };

    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    String key;
    for ( int i : a ) {
        key = String.valueOf( i );
        if ( counts.containsKey( key ) ) {
            int count = counts.get( key );
            counts.put( key, ++count );
        }
        else {
            counts.put( key, 1 );
        }
    }

    for ( Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet() ) {
        if ( entry.getValue() < 2 ) {
            System.out.println( entry.getKey() + " does not have a pair" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was unable to think of such a solution in a mins time which he had given me. :(

Comment: You don't need to get the `int` as a `String`, just do a `Map<Integer,Integer>` and it's ok =)

Answer (score 0):

There is an example which is listed in codility example and I test this code there and found some in correctness for some of the test cases with also bad performance