# find the element that appears once in the array when others appear twice

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I wrote the code with o(n^2) complexity.I could not find the error.My idea was to first sort the array and then starting from the first element if the second next is equal increment i by 2 and when the if condition is not fulfilled the element is found Can someone please help me this. 
Thanks in advance

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int arr[100];
int n,i,j,temp;
cin>>n;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>arr[i];
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>arr[j])
        {
            temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
i=0;
for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
{
    if(arr[i] == arr[j])
    {
        i=i+2;
    }
}
cout<<arr[i];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try running your program line by line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables, to see what is going wrong?

Comment: i tried running it line by line too. The code gives the garbage value @AndreasWenzel

Comment: You might be interested in this question: [find the only unpaired element in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2644179/445976)

Comment: Well where in the code is the first time that you see a garbage value?

Comment: @BessìeTheCow after incrementing i by 2. Cout<<arr[i] gives the garbage value

Answer (score 3):

To find a non-repetitive element in an array the first thing that comes to mind is that if we first sort the array and then try to manipulate it. The sorting process is easy and as follows:

```
    int arr[] = {/*Some array*/};
    int arrSize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    //Lets sort the array
    for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<arrSize;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]>arr[j])
            {
                int t=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=t;
            }
        }
    }
```

After sorting the array we may see different scenarios like:

```
int arr1[] = {1,1,2,2,3};
int arr2[] = {1,2,2,3,3};
int arr3[] = {1,1,2,3,3};
```

We have to design an algorithm such that it can differentiate and easily manipulate the three scenarios. Let n be our number. The first scenario is to check if the last isn't the same as the previous one by:

```
    if(arr[arrSize-1] != arr[arrSize-2]) //The last is not the same as the previous
    {
        n=arr[arrSize-1];
    }
```

The second one is similar to the first:

```
    if(arr[0] != arr[1]) // The first element is not the same as the second
    {
        n = arr[0];
    }
```

The third one is easy too, we just have to check if two neighbors are never equal to the middle number, this is as follows:

```
        for(int i=1;i<arrSize-1;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i-1] != arr[i] && arr[i] != arr[i+1])
            {
                n=arr[i];
                break;
            }
        }
```

And so the full code would become:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,2,3,1};
    int arrSize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    //Lets sort the array
    for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<arrSize;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]>arr[j])
            {
                int t=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=t;
            }
        }
    }
    int n;
    if(arr[0] != arr[1]) // The first element is not the same as the second
    {
        n = arr[0];
    }
    else if(arr[arrSize-1] != arr[arrSize-2]) //The last is not the same as the previous
    {
        n=arr[arrSize-1];
    }
    else //Lets search for a number such that its not the same as the numbers on the left and on the right
    {
        for(int i=1;i<arrSize-1;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i-1] != arr[i] && arr[i] != arr[i+1])
            {
                n=arr[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << n;
}
```

The Second Way (Better one).

Here's another way we could solve this problem. Suppose that I have a number n=3, if i XORed it with 3 i will get 0, so if we have an array lets say arr[] = {1,2,1}, I first assign n=0, then XOR it with the firs element (1), next I XOR n with the second element and then with the third element. What will happen? The third XOR will cancel the effect of the first thus n will equal to 1. Sample Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,2,3,1};
    int arrSize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    int n=0;
    for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        n^=arr[i];
    }
    cout << n;
}
```

This code is O(n).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to write `for(int j=i+1;j<arrSize;j++)` instead of `for(int j=i;j<arrSize;j++)` in the first code snippet? That way, the sorting algorithm would no longer compare an element with itself. I really like the XOR solution, by the way. :)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yes you can, I wrote this on the fly so I didn't optimize it very well and the XOR version is very famous I suggest you read more or research more about it

Answer (score 1):

Use XOR. XOR of all array elements gives us the number with a single occurrence.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int singleoccurence(int arr[], int n)
{
    int res = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        res = res ^ arr[i];
    }

    return res;
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {7, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int val = singleoccurence(arr, n);
    cout << "ELEMENT OCCURING ONLY ONCE IS :" << val;
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073) Please edit your code to use the relevant ***standard*** header files.

Comment: @AdrianMole.Can u please explain like what u want to say.in the above code  #include<bits/stdc++.h> is used as it includes all standard library but its optional u can simply use #include<iostream>

Answer (score 0):

Solution in C#

```
public static int lonelyinteger(List<int> a)
{
    int lonely = 0;
    foreach(var item in a)
    {
        List<int> listTemp = a.Where(x => x == item).ToList();
        if(listTemp.Count == 1)
            lonely = listTemp.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return lonely;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).